# The sums of squares from standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to figure out how to get a sum of squares from a standard deviation. The standard deviations I have are $11.04$, $9.91$ and $9.43$. How do I calculate the sum of squares associated with these standard deviation values? Thanks!

Comment: As @MartinVesely (+1) has shown in his Answer, it isn't enough to know the variances. If you know both the sample mean and the sample variance, then you can deduce the sum of squares.

Answer (score 2):

It holds that
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \Big[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\Big] - (\bar{x})^2
$$

hence we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\ = n[\sigma^2+(\bar{x})^2].
$$

Note that $\bar{x}$ is arithmetic mean and $n$ is number of observation.